# angular is not defined when using async attribute

Tags: angularjs

When I try to use the attribute `async` on my script tags, I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>
> Module 'app.main' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

When looking on the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization), I saw the recommendation to bootstrap it manually, so I did this:

```
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>

    <script async>
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app.main']);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

> I know async should be used when the script is at the beggining of the page, but in both situations I had the same error.

As you can see, I tried to manually bootstrap my application at the end. I also tried using that same code inside my `app.min.js` file, at the end of the file, but both scenarios gave me the same results.

If I remove the attr async, everything gets back to normal and work again, but how am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you want them to load async? Unless you use a load manager you hve no control over execution order of those 3 scripts. Objviously the last one doesn't require time for download and is likely to execute first ... before angulr is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know

```
Note: The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present).
```

Thanks :)